# SQLAlchemy Adjacency List Relationships cascading not updating on parents

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

From the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/self_referential.html) I've been able to create the parent-child relationship that I need.

```
class Node(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_data = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('node.data'))
    data = db.Column(db.String(50))
    children = db.relationship("Node", remote_side=[data])
```

and then I create my objects and everything works fine

```
    node1 = Node(data='Node1')
    node2 = Node(data='Node2', children=node1)
    db.session.add(node2)
    db.session.commit()
```

But if I change the data in node1 (which is node2 child), node2.parent_data won't update accordingly.
Tried using backref for children, cascading the relationship but without success.

I can create many to many relationships with the same class using association tables, but would be very nice to get this working.

Comment: is there a reason you are linking parent and child using `data` and `parent_data` columns and not `id` and `parent_id` (instead of `parent_data`)? Usually relationships are established between ForeignKey and PrimaryKey.

Comment: Just so that the data in my table would be already there as it will be used. I actually tried setting `data` as primary_key, setting also unique=True, but the result is the same (no change in the parent_data). I get it working with id, both in  Adjacency List Relationships and association tables, was just wondering if it could be done.

Comment: I just realized that I was trying to put a `string` into an `integer` field. Changed it to `parent_data = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('node.data'))`, but still no luck...

Comment: Just on the terminology: _If you look at your test data, you will see that in fact `Node1` is the parent node and `Node2` is the child pointing back to the parent. The idea is that parent can have many children. This is just to be on the same page, because your relationship is called 'children', but in fact it is is 'parent' - the other side of the relationship._

Comment: _Having taking the terminology above into account_, I do not believe you should expect children nodes to update their ForeignKey values when the parent updates its value referenced by FKs (or vice-versa).
This is why my first question was about why not using PKs, which are not supposed to be modified, and are usually used as FK references. FKs can be modified though to either disassociate or to point to another parent.

So, I do not think there is any bug, it is just you are expecting something the systems are not designed to do.

What is the actual use case? Maybe another solution?